# getting repeated data from mysql select statement

Tags: mysql

My name is Srinivas i am doing a school management software in php using mysql as a db.

pl any one help me, i have stucked in my sql query.

I'll explain my prob . I have two tables one is student and another table is marks

Each table has 5 rows 
when i execute select statement both tables results 5 records in each result.
this is the select statement i had wrote

For table Student :
`SELECT ta.rollno, ta.StdNm FROM tbl_student ta WHERE ta.Cls =22`

For table Marks : `SELECT tc.telugu FROM tbl_marks tc WHERE tc.Cid =22`

both resulting 5 records in each statement but when i combine them both it results 25 records instead of displaying 5 records

this is combined sql select:

`SELECT DISTINCT tc.rollno, tc.english, ta.rollno, ta.StdNm
FROM tbl_marks tc, tbl_student ta
WHERE tc.Cid =22
AND ta.Cls =22`

pl any one tell me where i am doing mistake in this statement

Comment: A join will give you all combinations. How do you want to match the rows up? Ie, if you have rows a, b, c, d and e from one table and z, y, x, w and v from the other table, how do you define whether row a gets matched up with z, y, x, w or v

Comment: use proper join so that u will get correct record. You are using cross join which is not correct

Comment: Do you have a separate column in marks for each subject?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT tc.rollno, tc.english, ta.rollno, ta.StdNm 
FROM tbl_marks tc, tbl_student ta 
WHERE tc.Cid =22 AND ta.Cls =22 AND ta.rollno=tc.rollno;
```

Comment: @user2553072- I dont think you need to select `rollno` from both the tables since they are the same, but i just improved upon your query, so i let it be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    tc.rollno, 
    tc.english, 
    ta.rollno, 
    ta.StdNm 
FROM 
    tbl_marks tc
LEFT JOIN tbl_student ta 
    ON ta.Cls = tc.Cid
WHERE 
    tc.Cid =22
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Joins`. Your query generates cross-product of individual queries thus resulting in 25 results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tc.rollno, tc.english, ta.rollno, ta.StdNm 
FROM tbl_marks tc
inner join tbl_student ta on ta.Cls = tc.Cid
WHERE ta.Cls =22
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) SQL query:
Try this:

```
SELECT tc.rollno, tc.english, ta.rollno, ta.StdNm 
FROM tbl_marks AS tc JOIN tbl_student AS ta ON tc.Cid = ta.Cls 
WHERE tc.Cid =22
```